# JavaScript передать значение функции в другую функцию как параметр

Tags: javascript

```js
finction a(string) {
  // Проверяет строку на корректные символы
  // Возвращает массив с цифрами [1, 1] 
}

finction b(string) {
  // Работает с вычислениями
  // Возвращает результат 
}
```

Как передать в функцию `b` возвращаемое значение из функции `a`, в качестве параметра:

```js
finction b([1, 1]) {
   
}
```

?

### реальный код

```js
romain2arabic('V + I')

function romain2arabic(string) {
  let arrSimvol = string.split(/[+*\/-]/g)
  
  let arrNum = []
  for (let i = 0; i < arrSimvol.length; i++) {
    let res = 0
    arrSimvol[i].replace(/[MDLV]|C[MD]?|X[CL]?|I[XV]?/g, function(i) {
      res = {M:1000, CM:900, D:500, CD:400, C:100, XC:90, L:50, XL:40, X:10, IX:9, V:5, IV:4, III:3, II:2, I:1}[i]
    })
  
    arrNum.push(res)
    
  }
  return arrNum // возвращает [ 5, 1 ]
  
}

function romainCalc(romain2arabic) {
  let x = romain2arabic
  
}
console.log(romainCalc()) // Получаю undefined
```

Comment: `b(a('тут параметры для "a"'))`

Comment: finction b(a(string)) {} - Так?

Comment: нет. Ты путаешь вызов функции и определение функции. Как вызвать функцию, указано в комментарии выше.

Comment: Просто смотри самый первый комментарий: `romainCalc(romain2arabic('V + I'))`

Answer (score 1):

```
let a = function1(bla);
let b = function2(a);
```

Comment: И внутри функции b я получаю undefined

Comment: @ИванКонкин значит функция это и возвращает

Comment: Добавил реальный код, как я делал.

Comment: @ИванКонкин почитай базу про объявление функций и их вызов. Естественно в твоём случае будет undefined, ведь ты вторую функцию вызываешь без передачи параметра

Comment: @ИванКонкин https://jsfiddle.net/e8mp3hug/

Answer (score 1):

в функции romainCalc() не хватает return. поэтому после ее выполнения получается undefined. нужно что-то возвращать из функции. добавьте, например, return x